# ASMX Web Service failed to send response back to browser

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, asmx

We recently moved to a new system and seeing an odd issue, but to preface, we are using javascript, classic asp, and asmx web services (until we can re-code).

our web services are setup in their own individual application pools on IIS 7.5.  The web service in question is coded in .net 4, and the app pool is setup in .net 4 "integrated".

We have multiple customers urls hitting another domain where our web services reside.
The application uses javascript ajax calls to hit our back end asp pages.
example:

```
https://DomainForCustomer/CustomersPage --> executes javascript ajax --> Classic ASP Code -->

Set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST",postUrl,false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.send DataToSend

where postURL = https://MainDomain/WebService/WebService.asmx/Method
```

I should also mention I configured the web service for GET/POST requests.

So what we are currently experiencing is short requests work fine, and fast.  Longer requests (approx 5-10 minutes) never get returned to a browser.

when I setup the same web service code under the same customer site in iis it runs fine.  I setup print statements to a file on the web service to see when my process finishes and can see when the data should be returned back to the browser but the website doesn't seem to receive it.

would anyone have any ideas on this or be able to point to any settings that might help.
I did look into the cross-origins stuff but that seems to pertain more to javascript, not asp (what I'm told anyways).

finally, with our current architecture, our web servers are going through a load balancer with ssl off loading, so I'm not sure if that would have anything to do with it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after more testing, it was determined that our ssl offloading was not configured correctly.  After changing that within our system this longer running process started working much better.

Additionally I was returning 160k + characters in my response to the browser so we added to our IIS config:

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" />
```

I know this is more particular to our config, but I hope this helps someone else in the future.